# Excel Averageifs with date criteria

Tags: excel-formula

I have 2 sheets called sheet1 and the other sheet2.

Info found on sheet1

Using columns a-d

```
Date       Product       qty used         actual qty used    
1-jan-16    aaaa          102                 50    
8-jan-16    aaaa          102                150

Date = 1 jan + 8 day till dec 31
```

sheet2 info

using columns a-d

```
Month     count        average    
Jan    
Feb    
Mar
```

The count columns uses the =count function works OK.

But the average gives an error.

This is what I'm trying to do is average out the actual column on sheet 1 using the month criteria on sheet2, so for the month Jan it looks at sheet1 and averages out the 4 week that have the month Jan found in it.

I get #DIV/0! error

```
=AVERAGEIFS('sheet1'!H157:H208,'sheet1'!B157:B208,">="&Sheet2!A4,'sheet1'!B157:B208,"<="&EOMONTH(Sheet2!A4,0))
```

If any info missing please feel free to ask.
Thanks

Comment: Are the months in column A on Sheet2 actual dates formated `mmm` or are then only the text `Jan,Feb,...`?

Comment: Thanks my month on sheet 2 was entered as a text..

Answer (score 1):

For some reason it doesn't `AVERAGEIFS` does not like cell referencing against date values (at least for multiple conditions).

Provided that the Months are entered as actual month values formatted as `mmm` (which I assume based on the formula you provided), this formula works (I tested it against your sample data (extrapolated)):

```
=AVERAGEIFS('sheet1'!H157:H208,'sheet1'!B157:B208,">="&Date(YEAR(A4),MONTH(A4),1),'sheet1'!B157:B208,"<"&DATE(YEAR(A4),MONTH(A4)+1,1))
```

Comment: thanks for the info...will be using this also but on another sheet